# How to use a specific locale?

Tags: android, localization, locale

Getting strings in Android is done automatically, based on the user's choice of which locale to set for the device. However, sometimes the user might want to have a locale to be different across apps (for example, French for program A and English for program B).

I have some questions regarding using a specific locale:

1. Is it possible to run an external app, and telling it that the current locale is X (or use a specific locale)? If so, how?
2. Is it possible to run the current app, and telling it that the current locale is X?
   if so, how?
3. Is it possible to get a string in the current app (using getString, for example), using a specific locale X? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but you are against the android system.

You can set the language for each activity with something like that :

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

you can find an another way to change the configuration [here](http://spinettaro.blogspot.fr/2012/03/resources-based-on-localization.html)

Comment: what does this code do ? which of my questions did you answer? the rest are impossible ? besides, how could it be against the android system if the user has chosen it this way ? for example , i would like to have my news apps written in hebrew , but the rest of the apps in english . i don't see any problem with that .

Comment: Sorry, i answered quickly. I answer to the 2 if current app means a app that you're coding. This code changes the android ressource configuration for your activity. With it the user can choose among several language for the app itself. This methode is against the android system because android does not give a way to change the locale, its only a tricks you must apply on each activity. So I think the 1 is impossible, and i don't really know for 3.

Comment: For the 1, indeed, it seems impossible : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3012059/1720391,

Comment: i don't understand. for which question did you answer with the code , and what about the other questions ?

Answer (score 0):

For the question 2, 3: I used the following way to set a specific locale to my app, despite of the locale of the device (for example: my device's default locale is set to Japan, but my app will start in the locale of the US):

extends the Application class, named MyApp class, and in the onCreate method, add the following snippet:

```
public static Configuration mConfig;

public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   ...
   mConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
   mConfig.locale = new Locale(user_locale); // user_locale is your self-defined locale
   getResources().updateConfiguration(mConfig, null);
}
```

In addition, you have to define this in your Manifest file, main activity part:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

By this way, I can do what you want in the question 2 and 3. Note that when you want to (or you really do) change the locale to another one, you have to re-start your application.

Hope that help.

Comment: This actually sounds more like an answer to #2 alone, since I can't get the string of more than 1 locale , only the current one being used.